# I couldn't find it when I tried to use spring security for permission selection

Tags: java

I can get user information in the code when I log in again, but I can't get it on the front end.

I did the following

```
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws 
  UsernameNotFoundException {
    log.info("开始查找用户：" + username);
    User userInfo = baseMapper.selectOne(new LambdaQueryWrapper<User> ().select().eq(User::getUsername, username));
    if (userInfo != null) {
    //查询权限信息
    String role[enter image description here][1]=roleMapper.selectById(userInfo.getRoleId()).getRoleName();
    List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = ofAuthority(role);
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(username, 
         userInfo.getPassword(), authorities);
       }
    throw new UsernameNotFoundException("用户名不存在...");
   }

/**
 * 角色控制
 *
 * @param args
 * @return
 */
public List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> ofAuthority(String args) {
    String[] roles = args.split(",");
    List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String role : roles) {
        System.out.println("当前角色拥有权限：" + "ROLE_" + role);
        list.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role));
    }
    return list;
}
```

I made a permission judgment, I hope it will not be displayed, because I don't have ADMIN permission, but he still shows it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQEZd.png)

Comment: You might want to edit the question rather than answer it. [edit]